# Dark GTK themes under GNOME are not displayed well in some applications

Tags: themes, gtk, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I'm working under Ubuntu 17.04, with GNOME shell in a Wayland session. Setting up (using gnome-tweak-tool) a dark theme - Adwaita dark, Breeze dark - works for most of the native GNOME applications, but not for other GTK applications that are supposed to work well with.

I.e. most of the menu options are not visible do to white font over light background, and depending on the theme not even the menus themselves appear. I also noticed the same issue in text inputs, like the Google Chrome URL bar.

For instance, this is how Thunar is displayed under Adwaita dark:

[image: Thunar under Adwaita dark]

And this is how it is displayed under Breeze dark:

[image: Thunar under Breeze dark]

Comment: Looks like a bug in XWayland.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the Desktop Environment. Use Alt+F2 and then type `r` This could fix the problems caused by switching themes.